# print first 10 working days in a month using python

Tags: python

Could you please help me with a script that prints the first 10 working days or weekdays in a specified month and year to a file?

In my case, the month and year values are specified in a file and the content of the file looks like this:

```
MAR-21
```

I am new to programming and with my searching and self study, I was able to create the below code. I think this is giving me correct output but not really sure on how to get this saved to a file and also on how to use the above file as parameters.

```
import calendar

from datetime import date, timedelta

def first_workday(month, year):
    first = date(year, month, 1)
    return first if first.weekday() < 5 else first.replace(day=8 - first.weekday())

# get year value from Year file
with open('C:/Users/DocsAgent/syscontrol/Year.txt','r') as file:
    year = file.read().replace('\n','')
print(year)

def table(year = 2021):
    print('\n'.join(' %2i) %s' %
                    (month, first_workday(month,year).strftime('%a %m/%d/%Y'))
                    for month in range(1,13)))
    # Produces three letter weekday name instead of two letters

table()
```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see how to create a [mre], and specifically, consider adding some of your attempts, some example input (more than just a single date), and your expected output.

Comment: Wrt _" I think this is giving me correct output but not really sure on how to get this saved to a file"_ - then read the docs on [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). What do you mean by  _"how to use the above file as parameters"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime("MAR-21", "%b-%y")
weekdaycount = 0
while weekdaycount < 10:
    if date.weekday() in [0,1,2,3,4]:
        print(date)
        weekdaycount += 1
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, Sander. With a few edits, I was able to get what I needed with the help of your code.